# AWS free tier "sign up date" vs "credit card details submission date"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am worried about my account expiry date.

I created an account on AWS in July 2013 and submitted my credit card details on 31st Oct 2013. I went in Billing Management Console/Bills section where when I click on Date, I can see months ranging from July 2013 to Nov 2013.

From AWS FAQs I gathered

```
When does the AWS free usage tier expire?
The AWS free usage tier will expire 12 months from the date you sign up.
```

So WHEN will my account expire, July 2014 (sign up date) or Oct 2014 (credit card details submission date) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your free account expired in July 2014 and not in Oct 2014.
**12 Months of Free Tier starts from your sign up** and free period are not related to adding a credit card or starting the first service or other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's strange for me that you were actually fully registered before you've verified yourself with a credit card. In my case I was not able to use the services and they said that ... in a couple days we.

But anyway, you should not be worrying much on that. In a month before the term finishes, they will send you an email warning about that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to get the date of registry with AWS is through an email search (unless you delete your emails).

Searching for "aws account" should fetch a small enough list to quickly sift through.

Answer (score -2):

It will expire 12 months after 31st Oct 2013 since you have no invoices prior to that date